# Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript

I'd like to build a rich text editor for a web site. How would I go about this? I've heard of iframe use for such a thing. Also contentEditable set to true plays a role. Could you tell me what you know about implementing a WYSIWYG editor? It would be nice...

Comment: What type of capabilities do you need? For example, should it have a math editor? Drawing tools? File upload capabilities? Or, just changing fonts, sizes, weights?

Comment: Hi James! I think it would be all about changing fronts, sizes and the like. The one that works with text.

Answer (score 7):

Consider saving yourself a lotta headache and look at [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), [FCKEditor/CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), and [CuteEditor](http://cutesoft.net/) (commercial). My personal favorite at the moment is CKEditor - its evolved very nicely and is pretty easy to use now

The recently released [Google Closure Library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/index.html) has capability to build rich text editors as well tho I have not yet any experience with that one - dunno its limitations if any

Comment: no ads plz no ads plz no ads plz

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel then you can look for some editors like

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

which comes with a lot of features.

Answer (score 1):

Please try some open source Rich text editor that will help you

One I know and used is [openwebware](http://www.openwebware.com/)

**About iframe** 
  I think every Rich text editor uses iframe. The editor above is also using iframe.

**About contentEditable** 
  This is used to make a element editable in browser it self. You can find this in the editor mentioned above.

Do try this editor will help you.

Comment: It doesn't support Google Chrome... Which is just about to surpass Firefox in the number of users...

Answer (score 1):

I built one from scratch using the Mozilla MIDAS specification.  Keep in mind that this won't work well with IE (at least mine doesn't).

Specification - http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html

Demo - http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midasdemo/

I use the demo source (which it pretty clean) to construct my own editor for my CMS.

Good Luck!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to build your own then there are a few good [tutorials](http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/wysiwyg/wysiwyg1.asp) around.

Otherwise, here are another couple of good third-party editors that haven't been mentioned yet:

- [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)
- [RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx)