# Rich text formatting (RTF) editor plugins for Rails 3 and jQuery website?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, richtextbox

Which RTF editor do you use?

We're on Rails 3 and jQuery and looking to implement a low-maintenance RTF editor. We prefer to use a third-party plugin rather than build from scratch.

Which one do you use today, and what are the pros/cons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207774/what-is-the-best-rich-textarea-editor-for-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672099/is-there-an-open-source-javascript-rich-text-editor-similar-to-gmails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892427/rich-text-editor

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Could you reply as an answer, and I'll mark you as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery), its also customizable easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/). It is easy to use and also customizable.